# JS Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have added scrolling on my page. Below is my code

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.display-center a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var section=jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(section).offset().top-100
}, 1000);

        });
});
```

IT gaves Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null. Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the value of an href attribute as a selector in jQuery. You could define an `id` or a `data` attribute in your link like `<a href="..." data-scrollTo="myDiv" class="display-center">..</a>`. Now your corresponding element where you want to scroll to should have this `id` set to the value you defined in the `data-scrollTo` attribute like this: `<div id="myDiv">...</div>`.
Then you can use it with your code like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.display-center a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var section=jQuery(this).data('scrollTo');
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: jQuery("#"+section).offset().top-100
        }, 1000);
    });
 });
```